# PROPERTY LIST - Can't see all items in Episerver back end, is this a bug?

Tags: episerver

I am working on my first Episerver Project and I have come across a problem with the UI.

I have a block Type with a PROPERTY LIST property. However when I add more than five items you can't see them all in UI.

I have another 10 Rows I can't see.... 
Is this a bug in Episerver??[image]

Comment: Please post your code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the bug where the Episerver Forms addon [restricted the height of the PropertyList editor](https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/-Episerver-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2017/1/episerver-forms-breaks-propertylist-editor/).

It was fixed in `Episerver.Forms` version **4.4.1**: [Bug report](https://world.episerver.com/support/bug-list/bug/AFORM-940)

Perhaps this is the issue you're facing? If so, make sure to upgrade the site's NuGet packages.

Comment: Looks like it, I am using episerver 10 - its my first project so I am not sure what exactly I would have to do to upgrade "Episerver.Forms" can you expand your answer with a solution?

Comment: Did you upgrade to the most recent NuGet packages?

Comment: Upgraded Nuget Package to Episerver.Forms 4.4.4 - Fixed! Thank you guys.